# TFS 2013 Work Item Field not being highlighted when set to <required>

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I ran into some issues with TFS 2013 when I noticed some work items fields with the

```
<Required>
```

tag are highlighted when empty (shows up as yellow) but some are not highlighted. I don't seem to be able to find the reason as to why this is, the only difference I saw between the fields were that the types are different. Some are "string' and some are "HTML".

Is this because TFS can not highlight fields with data type "HTML"?

If someone can help me clarify this it'll be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is by design but the reason for such behavior is not the field type but control type you use to display it on work item form.

I've just checked on my local TFS instance that when I make System.Description field (which is HTML) read-only and then add FieldControl to display it on the form (instead of HtmlFieldControl) I get the same behavior as with System.Title (which is of type String). Now System.Description field control is highlighted when it's empty.

Here's the control I used to check it:

```
<Control FieldName="System.Description" Type="FieldControl" ControlFontSize="large" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I noticed that the Description field is also under HTMLfieldControl and if I set that to required, it is highlighted, but my own customized field is not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your assumption to be correct, the type of field will affect TFS's ability to highlight the field when required.
Your users should get an error message if they try to save WI with an empty Required field regardless of field type though.